# How to change the background color and button color of a scrollbar?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, scrollbar

What I tried:

Scrollbar1.BackColor = Color.Black 'error

Scrollbar1.ButtonBackColor = Color.Black 'error

> Image example of what i want to do:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUspn.png)

Comment: What class exactly is Scrollbar1?  What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's basically impossible.

I think that link will be helpful
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C

hope it gets resolved